# sed line number specific substitution changes every pattern on using g option and here-string

Tags: bash, sed, quotes, herestring

When using **pipe** with or without global **g** option gives same result:

```
echo -e 'hi\nhello\nhi' | sed '1s/hi/hey/g'
hey
hello
hi
```

works for **here-string** as well when not using global **g** option:

```
sed '1s/hi/hey/' <<< $(echo -e 'hi\nhello\nhi')
hey hello hi
```

but when using global **g** option and **here-string** replaces the pattern at every line:

```
sed '1s/hi/hey/g' <<< $(echo -e 'hi\nhello\nhi')
hey hello hey
```

Why this change in the output when using the global substitution flag and when input comes through here-string?

Comment: Why not `<<<$'hi\nhello\nhi' sed '1s/hi/hey/g'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not got much to do with the `sed` script and does have a lot to do with the `bash` here-string notation and quotes.  Use `cat` instead of `sed` and you see:

```sh
$ echo -e 'hi\nhello\nhi' | cat
hi
hello
hi
$ cat <<< $(echo -e 'hi\nhello\nhi')
hi hello hi
$ cat <<< "$(echo -e 'hi\nhello\nhi')"
hi
hello
hi
$
```

So, you can see that with the unquoted here-string, you get three words on one line.  The `g` modifier on the `sed` command `1s/hi/hey/g` means that both occurrences of `hi` on the first line of input are changed.  In the absence of the `g` modifier, only the first occurrence on the first line is changed.  The third line never gets modified because the `1` in `1s/hi/hey/` limits the changes to the first line of input.

This also explains the 3 lines vs 1 line of output.